# PHP Extend Class Conditionally? (CodeIgniter 3 Use Case)

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, extend, hmvc

*I'm using the following scenario, but this doesn't necessarily pertain only to CodeIgniter*.

**HMVC**: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

**Internationalization (i18n)**: https://github.com/waqleh/codeigniter-language-in-url-internationalization

Both HMVC & i18n work by extending `CI_Config` (and related `CI_` classes).

To get i18n working **alongside** HMVC, I first have to require the appropriate HMVC file and then further extend that class.

So for example, `CI_Config` is extended by HMVC `MX_Config` and then further required & extended by i18n `MY_Config`.

But now i18n **only works if** HMVC is already in place.

What if HMVC is absent (no `MX_Config` and related)?

**I want i18n to work both with/without HMVC**.

Is there a way to conditionally require & extend one class or another? Or rather, extend `CI_Config` (and related) twice without collision? Or is there another way to accomplish what I want?

HMVC `MX_Config` partial:

```
/**
 * HMVC
 */
class MX_Config extends CI_Config
{
```

i18n `MY_Config` partial:

```
/* load HMVC's MX_Config class */
require APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Config.php";

/**
 * Language
 */
class MY_Config extends MX_Config
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localheinz's answer is valid but does not take into account:

CodeIgniter loads core files `CI_` & `MY_` **before** HMVC `MX_` . So there's no way to have `MY_` check if an `MX_` is declared.

Nor do I want to edit core `CI_` files as they are not meant to be modified.

**The working solution**:

Note: The same logic below can be applied to other `MY_` classes.

`MY_Config` partial:

```
/* load HMVC's MX_Config class */
if ( file_exists(APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Config.php") ) {
    require APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Config.php";
/* otherwise declare MX_Config class */
} else {
    class MX_Config extends CI_Config {}
}


/**
 * Language
 */
class MY_Config extends MX_Config
{
```

Answer (score 2):

How about declaring the class `MX_Config` dynamically, if it doesn't exist?

```
<?php

class CI_Config {}

if (!class_exists('MX_Config')) {
    class MX_Config extends CI_Config {}
}

class MY_Config extends MX_Config {}

$config = new MY_Config();

var_dump(
    $config instanceof MX_Config,
    $config instanceof CI_Config
);
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/3pXGt

Comment: CodeIgniter loads core files `CI_` & `MY_` **before** HMVC `MX_` . So there's no way to have `MY_` check if an `MX_` is declared.

Nor do I want to edit core `CI_` files as they are not meant to be modified.

But your answer did help me a bit to formulate the correct solution taking CodeIgniter into account.